# When sort the products,product name displayed as ' UNDEFINED' magento1

Tags: product-sorting

When sort the products,product name displayed as ' UNDEFINED'  magento1.How to solve this.?

Answer (score 0):

For sorting products using product name you have to use **addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');** filter on product collection. Try this code it should be work.